# Motioneyeos not booting on my Raspberry pi 3B

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues, picamera

Stuck at this message “Formatting data partition” while trying to boot MotioneyeOS from a Raspberry pi 3B. I’ve flashed a 32GB microSD with the motioneyeos image file using Etcher. Is the problem with the SD card?[image] Please advise.

Comment: Does your RPi work if you try RaspiOS on it?

Comment: Yes, it does! I've been using the same RPi for a while with RaspiOS on a different SD card. Then I bought a new SD card and flashed the motioneyeos on it using Balena Etcher. When I try to boot it the first time, its stuck at this message "Formatting Data Partition"...Could it be an SD card issue? (I connected it to my PC and there seems to be no issue).

Comment: Download this: https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/releases/download/20200606/motioneyeos-raspberrypi3-20200606.img.xz and use this: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager_latest.exe to write it to your SDCard.

Answer (score 1):

with big size SSD/miscroSD's just keep calm until the disk is partitioned, for me it was some around 30 minutes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121295)